# logging data to the intermediate service

Tags: logs, application

I've two applications. They log in to a locked log file (with reading permissions). I want to use an intermediate service where applications can push logs. Then this service push that log to the log files. Is there any working solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Linux distribution usually has one by-default. Look up rsyslog, syslog-ng, etc. See, for example, https://www.rsyslog.com/ .

On modern systems, there is also a systemd journal which sometimes replaces syslog daemons. Over time, I discovered some of its quirks in practical deployments and I am avoiding it ever since. :)

You can also use some "extra" application like Logstash. It comes with a cost of heavier app, which can consume significant resources, but it greatly expands what you can do with your logs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I want to first receive the data from 2 apps then merge and finally push to logs. Can rsyslog do that?

Comment: You can merge logs from multiple applications into one logfile, that is one of most basic usecases and also essentially how logging into `/var/log/messages` and other compound logfiles works on a Linux.

However, I suggest you read the documentation to make sure a particular app suits your needs.